# How many zeros are obtained if we multiply all the natural numbers from 1 to 100?

Tags: contest-math

Options are:

1. 20
2. 21
3. 22
4. 23
5. 24

I recently came across the above question in a competitive exam, where we get about 30 seconds to 1 minute for solving each problem. I want to if there are  quick and easy methods to compute the result.

Comment: HINT: The number of $0$'s in a number is equal to the number of times $10$ divides it.

Comment: @MarcusM That is not true: consider, for instance, $101$.

Comment: I think Marcus may have chosen a more accurate duplicate, in hindsight, but I'll leave mine up, just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, the number of $0$s at the end of $k!$ is equal to
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{k}{5^i}\right\rfloor$$

The above expression is a measure of how many times $5$ divides $k!$.

Answer (score 3):

A zero can only occur as result of multiplying 5 with 2.
so consider the factors 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100 now Tolal number of 5 that can be obtained from these factor are 24.so there wiil be 24 zero.

Comment: Instead of writing a brand new answer, it is better practice to fix the one that's being downvoted.

Comment: @CameronBuie,thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @michael Zero can also occur by multiplying 0 by 0(10x10=100). I didn't quiet get the solution, could you please elaborate.

Comment: @AuraWanderer,since if we have a number ending with say one zero than it must be result of presence of 5 and 2 in its factor like 20=5*2*2,so here we have a pair (5,2).similarly for number ending with two zero say 200=5*5*2*2*2 so we have two five's here which after multiplication with 2 will make out two zero.hope this will help.